# fix error Cannot POST /students/image in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, driver, native, multer

I am trying to upload an image using multer to my MongoDB database. but I am getting an error in postman that says

```
    <pre>Cannot POST /students/image</pre>
```

I am new to mongodb. i am not allowed to use mongoose, because my company uses native driver instead of mongoose.

this is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();
const { connectToDb, getDb }  = require('./dbconnection');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('images'));

let db;

connectToDb((err) => {
    if(!err){
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, (req, res) => {
            console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
        });

        db =  getDb();
    }
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    //destination for files
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, '/images');
    },
  
    //add back the extension
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    },
  });
  
  //upload parameters for multer
  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
      fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 * 3,
    },
  });
app.post('/students', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const student = req.body;

    db.collection('student')
    .insertOne(student)
    .then(result => {
        res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({error: "Unable to create a new data"})
    })
});
```

this is my dbconnection.js file

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

let dbConnection;

module.exports = {
    connectToDb: (cb) => {
        MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/StudentsData')
        .then((client) => {
            dbConnection = client.db()
            return cb()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err)
        })
    },
    getDb: () => dbConnection
}
```

This is my db

```
[
    {
        "name": "Anand",
        "age": 25,
        "course": "computer science",
        "year of completion": 2021,
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Bivin",
        "age": 26,
        "course": "computer science",
        "year of completion": 2021,
        "image": ""
    }
]
```

My file system

```
images(folder)
node_modules(folder)
.env
app.js
dbconnection.js
package.json
```

how to fix this bug
I am not allowed to use mongoose since my company uses native drivers of MongoDB.

Comment: mongodb is noSQL, there is *no* schema. you have to write your own object building code that validates user input.

Comment: The path is `/students` are you calling  `/students/image` from postman.

Comment: @Charchit Kapoor bro when i call /students it stored the image I'm my image folder but not in db

Comment: To store the file in MongoDB, you need to use gridfs, using multer will not work.

Comment: I solved it by adding this code in post request

    `const img = req.file.filename;
    let image = {
        "image":img
    }
    let student = Object.assign(studentform, image);`